# Как с библиотеки достучатся к элементам TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал я библиотеку классов. Хочу в нём приписать метод, который будет включать в себе параметры такие как(TextBox, PasswordBox ....)

Если прописать его в самом классе (Там где проект, то он понимает эти параметры)

Но когда я пытаюсь прописать его в самой библиотеке, он не видит такие элементы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если <s>ваша библиотека под .NET Framework</s> у вас проектный файл «старого» стиля (начинается с `<?xml ...?><Project ToolsVersion=...`; скорее всего это так, если ваш проект под .NET Framework), просто добавьте ссылки на PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFramework.dll, System.Xaml.dll и WindowsBase.dll.

Если хотите, чтобы в проекте появлялись пункты меню наподобие Add → UserControl, вам придётся вручную отредактировать файл с проектом (для этого проще всего временно закрыть Студию), и добавить туда в верхнюю PropertyGroup следующее:

```xml
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Альтернативно, можно пересоздать библиотеку, используя тип библиотеки «WPF Class Library», так, наверное, будет проще.

Если <s>ваша библиотека под .NET Core или .NET 5+</s> у вас проектный файл «нового» стиля (то есть начинается с `<Project Sdk=...`; скорее всего это так, если ваш проект под .NET Core или .NET 5+), загляните в ваш проектный файл (это можно сделать прямо в Студии, не закрывая проект).

Под .NET 5 ваш файл должен выглядеть как-то так:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

(вам нужно `net5.0-windows`, а не `net5.0` в качестве `TargetFramework`, и проверьте, чтобы `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` присутствовало в какой-то `PropertyGroup`).

Под .NET Core и .NET Framework должно выглядеть как-то так:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

(то есть, убедитесь, что ваш SDK = `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop`, а не `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, и проверьте, чтобы `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` присутствовало в какой-то `PropertyGroup`).

И не забудьте добавить `using System.Windows.Controls;` или где там находятся ваши контролы.

Comment: У меня библиотека под .NET Framework.

Добавил все ссылки, и всё ровно не находит тип TextBox

вот фотография https://cloud.mail.ru/public/wrgY/bn4XGjApK

Comment: @Кирилл: А что говорит при компиляции? Может, у вас опечатка в using?

Comment: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "TextBox" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: @Кирилл: А using вы не забыли?

Comment: Так мы же в ссылки добавляли библиотеки PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFramework.dll, System.Xaml.dll и WindowsBase.dll.

Зачем ещё using ?

Comment: А всё, решил проблему. Я думал он сам заработает, но теперь он работает, так как я ещё using System.Windows.Controls; добавил

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться)

Comment: @Кирилл: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!